# Span selected Nodes after have declared the number of comumns and rows in javafx

Tags: javafx

I would like to know the way to span the next node in the second column after the node containing the label "Info" to the rest of the remaining columns and on 3 rows below.

Below is my present output with the associated code.

[image]

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        final int numCols = 5 ;
        final int numRows = 12 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints colConst = new ColumnConstraints();
            colConst.setPercentWidth(100.0 / numCols);
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(colConst);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            RowConstraints rowConst = new RowConstraints();
            rowConst.setPercentHeight(100.0 / numRows);
            root.getRowConstraints().add(rowConst);         
        }
        
        Label nameLbl = new Label("Name");
        Label nameFld = new Label();
        Label infoLbl = new Label("Info : ");
        Label infoFld = new Label();
        infoFld.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lavender;-fx-font-size: 7pt;-fx-padding: 10 0 0 0;");   

        Button okBtn = new Button("OK");
        Button cancelBtn = new Button("Cancel");
        
        Label commentBar = new Label("Status: Ready");
        commentBar.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lavender;-fx-font-size: 7pt;-fx-padding: 10 0 0 0;");       
        
        root.add(nameLbl, 0, 0, 1, 1);   
        root.add(nameFld, 1, 0, 1, 1);   
        root.add(infoLbl, 0, 1, 1, 1);  
        root.add(infoFld, 1, 1, 4, 4);  
        root.add(okBtn, 3, 9, 1, 1);    
        root.add(cancelBtn, 2, 9, 1, 1); 
        root.add(commentBar, 0, 11, GridPane.REMAINING, 1);     
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the label to span four rows, as well as four columns, set its column span as well as its row span to 4:

```
    // root.add(infoFld, 1, 1, 4, 1);
    root.add(infoFld, 1, 1, 4, 4);
```

By default a label will not grow beyond its preferred size (which in this case is zero, because it has no text). Allow it to grow indefinitely:

```
infoFld.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
infoFld.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: With this method it seems that one cannot add paddings to the node.

Comment: @Space Why not?

Comment: I equally tried root.setPadding and/or infoFld.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lavender;-fx-font-size: 7pt;-fx-padding: 10;-fx-border-color:black;"); but I still get the same output as diplyed above.

Comment: @Space Well, yes. That will just add padding between the edges of the label and its content. Just use the appropriate `GridPane` methods. Read the documentation.